# Create a clustered table in BigQuery from existing table with _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl

I am trying to make a new clustered table, `db.new_table`, that have the same data and schema as an existing table, `db.old_table`, in BigQuery. The existing table have a pseudo column `_PARTITIONTIME`, and I would like the new table to have this `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column as well.

I have tried using DDL, with query like:

```
CREATE TABLE `db.new_table`
PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
CLUSTER BY field1, field2
AS SELECT * FROM `db.old_table`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME > '1990-01-01'
```

However it failed because we cannot use `PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)` followed by `AS SELECT ...`.  as stated in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language

Is there a methods to do this? (create a new clustered table with the same exact schema and data from an old table partitioned by pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME )

Any answer and comment is appreciated, thanks.

---

Notes:
I can create a similar table without _PARTITIONTIME with query like:

```
CREATE TABLE `db.new_table`
PARTITION BY partition_date
CLUSTER BY field1, field2
AS SELECT DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) AS partition_date, * FROM `db.old_table`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME > '1990-01-01'
```

However since a lot of things in the system depend on `db.old_table`, the change in partition field from `_PARTITIONTIME` to `partition_date` would cause a lot of query changes... Therefore it would be much preferable if we can create the clustered table with exactly same schema and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pre-create your day-partitioned, clustered table (on whatever fields) named `db.new_table` using either BQ UI or `bq` command.

Once the table is there, you can populate "for each day" as:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --append_table --noflatten_results --destination_table 'db.new_table$19900101' "select field1, field2, field3 from db.old_table where _PARTITIONTIME = '1990-01-01'";
```

Notice two things:

- You have to run this query for each day separately (which will cost you pretty much the same so don't worry about it).
- The `db.new_table$19900101` points to the partition of `1990-01-01` in `db.new_table`.